# Error because virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I was trying to install a CMS in a folder in my website. After the installation and trying to run, it shows this error:

> Error 14 It is an error to use a
>   section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond application level.  This error
>   can be caused by a virtual directory
>   not being configured as an application
>   in
>   IIS. E:\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\WebSites\WebSite20\blog\web.config 61

I added the website as a Virtual Directory and also converted that to application. On trying to browse this application, the following error occurs as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you're now past the not-configured-as-an-application problem? The error in your screenshot is file-not-found. Does that path (E:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebAssitBlog) exist? Was that supposed to be 'Assist' or 'Asset' not 'Assit'? Does it work if you add a trailing forward slash to the request URL? Do you have an URL filter installed (as mentioned in the screenshot)? If that's all OK, try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which file it's trying to open and failing.

Comment: I changed the port number of the webiste to something like 9020 and it I was able to browse it. However, in visual Studio, I am still getting this error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error I believe now is that you need to setup the Default Document.  Go into IIS and select the Default Document option (IIS 6 or 7, has to be installed), and set it to the default page you'd like to show.  Or type in the path with the ASPX document included.  So enter: http://localhost/mysite/default.aspx, or set the default document as default.aspx. That's typically the cause.

HTH.